# The constant confusion

Tags: java, android

I just started reading [Head First Android Development](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491974052) and I'm little confused about the code in chapter 3.

The first activity **CreateMessageActivity** is sending an intent to the second activity *ReceiveMessageActivity*, so far so good.

```
public class CreateMessageActivity extends Activity
{
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_create_message);
    }

    // Call this when the button is clicked
    public void onSendMessage(View view)
    {
        EditText messageView = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.message);
        String messageText = messageView.getText().toString();
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, messageText);
        String chooserTitle = getString(R.string.chooser);
        Intent chosenIntent = Intent.createChooser(intent, chooserTitle);
        startActivity(chosenIntent);
    }
}
```

The second activity **ReceiveMessageActivity** gets the intent from the first activity *CreateMessageActivity*.

```
public class ReceiveMessageActivity extends Activity
{
    public static final String EXTRA_MESSAGE = "message";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_receive_message);
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        String messageText = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);
        TextView messageView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message);
        messageView.setText(messageText);
    }
}
```

I can't understand the constant EXTRA_MESSAGE. If I change "message" to something like "asdfwerf324wd23" the code will still compile and run without problems. Even if I remove the constant EXTRA_MESSAGE and give intent.getStringExtra a random "name", the app will work fine. What's the purpose of this constant?

I have to mention that I'm somewhat new to Android/Java programming and I'm trying to understand the connections between the classes.

Comment: what do u need ?

Comment: if you delete the constant, the code will just do the same thing without it. the question is why is this constant there?

Comment: if u need converting into a `String` so used `getStringExtra()`

Comment: "The first activity CreateMessageActivity is sending an intent to the second activity ReceiveMessageActivity" -- no, it is not. It will start the user's choice of activity, among those that support `ACTION_SEND` for `text/plain`. `ReceiveMessageActivity` does not support `ACTION_SEND` (or, if it is supposed to, it has bugs, as it should be getting the shared text using `Intent.EXTRA_TEXT` as the key to the `Bundle`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constant defines the key to look for in the bundle.

Bundles are basically (at the core) maps containing a key with an associated value. If a key doesn't exist, null is returned. Meaning if nothing is passed with a given value of the key, the method `get[type]Extra` returns null.

You can set null as the text to a TextView without it throwing any exceptions. In the TextView code, the String is set to `""` if it's null. So essentially:

```
String messageText = intent.getStringExtra(EXTRA_MESSAGE);//this ends up being null
TextView messageView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.message);
messageView.setText(messageText);//and this sets the text to ""
```

The reason it works no matter which key you pick is because it returns null. If you don't send anything with that key though, it'll never have an actual value when you retrieve it, and the TextView will be empty

Comment: Now I finally understand what's going on, at least I know where to look next. You explained it very well, thank you! :)